# Pthread- limit number of threads that can access a function at a time

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I have a quick question. I'm learning about semaphores and I want only **four** threads to be able to access someFunction() at any given time. This function needs to execute **num_task** times. This is what I have so far, but valgrind is throwing some errors saying that I have possible **memory leaks**. Please tell me where I'm going wrong and how to go about fixing this. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t s; 
typedef struct Data Data;
struct Data {
    int index;
    int j; 
};
void* someFunction(void* arg){ 
    // make sure only four threads access this function at once
    sem_wait(&s);
    Data* a = arg;
    printf("i%d j%d\n", a->index, a->j);
    sleep(1);  
    free(a); 
    sem_post(&s); 
    return 0;
}  
int main(void){
    int num_task = 10; // i need to call someFunction() 9000 times
    int num_threads = 4;
    sem_init(&s, 0, num_threads);
    int j = 0;
    pthread_t thread_ids[num_threads];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_task; i ++){ // these are our columns 
        sem_wait(&s);
        if (j > num_threads - 1){
            j = 0; // j goes 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 ....
        } 
        Data* a = malloc(sizeof(Data));
        a->index = i;
        a->j = j; 
        printf("MAIN j%d\n", j);
        pthread_create(thread_ids + j, NULL, someFunction, a); 
        j ++;
        sem_post(&s); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i ++){
        pthread_join(thread_ids[i], NULL);
    }
    sem_destroy(&s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are leaking `pthread_t`s, because you are using each entry in `thread_ids` for multiple threads without `pthread_join()`ing in between. *Technically* that means you also have a race between terminating the threads that are not joined with and `return`ing from `main()`, as well as `sem_wait()/sem_post()` and `sem_destroy()`.

Comment: As EOF wrote which should be clear from valgrind. ==10084==    by 0x4012E54: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:296)

`==10084==    by 0x4E3FDA0: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:589) `
`==10084==    by 0x4E3FDA0: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:500)`

Comment: Thanks how do i go about fixing this?

Comment: Make sure to store and join ALL your thread IDs.